# Unity GameObject disappears after turning it into a prefab

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 3d game in Unity for a school project and I have followed several online tutorials. I made a simple door in Blender, imported it to Unity, and placed it in the scene and it worked fine, but then after I made some minor changes to it and then placed the new finished door object into my assets, the door object "disappeared". The object is still there in the scene hierarchy but it does not show up in the scene or game view. Instead, it is just an outline if selected and is otherwise not visible. [Outline of object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KDCYR.png)

I looked online and could not find any similar occurrences and could not find any, so I tried unpacking the object (which I did not expect to do anything) as I am very new to Unity. I also tried placing the object into a new scene, and later a new project, but both did not work.

Comment: when you check your inspector window and mesh filter component, do you see a mesh attached to it ? also could you attach your model's inspector window so we can see the settings.

Comment: Oh, I see what happened now! I think I accidentally deleted the mesh of the door which led to a floating handle. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad i was able to help. Take care.